# How do I write logs to docker container in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to configure my local logger to write the logs to the docker container, so I can see the logs in the list displayed by the command `docker[-compose] logs <container> --tail 100`

In `settings.py`, I configured `LOGGING` variable like this:

```
 LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '[DJANGO] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s '
                      '%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'default',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    },
}
```

In the files where I need the loggers, at the beginning, I am writing:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then, in my code where I need it I write:

```
.......
logger.error('something happened')
.......
```

As I configured my logger, the log will be displayed in the console. But my problem is:

How can I display it in docker container when I call the aforementioned command ?

Example like desired output:

```
........
web_1 | [2022-02-23 17:37:10 +0200] [9] [INFO] ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
web_1 | [2022-02-23 17:37:10 +0200] [9] [INFO] Application startup complete.
web_1 | [2022-02-23 17:37:10 +0200] [10] [INFO] Application startup complete.
web_1 | My log somewhere here..
........
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe add this command in you docker-compose to fire at startup.

```
docker logs --tail 1000 -f 'your_container_id_here'
```

Answer (score 1):

You did everything right in Django to make your logs visible in docker logs. The only thing that I spotted is that you propagate such logs to the higher-level handler (e.g. gunicorn). You have two options:

The first option is to avoid propagation by setting `propagate` to `False`:

```
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        }
    },
```

The other option is to configure your application server to avoid filtering, but this will depend on the configuration of your app server.

Comment: I tried, but for some reason, the docker logs stiil does not show me what I displayed, even though it is displayed in console. I might have another setup somewhere, that is in conflict and I have no idea what :(. 
Thanks for your reply mate ! Cheers!